# python plotly table, change color of a specific row

Tags: python, plotly

i am looking for a solution how to change the color a specific row (by row name and/or position). I my chase, i would like to calculate a total in the last row and change the color.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores'],
                line_color='darkslategray',
                fill_color='lightskyblue',
                align='left'),
    cells=dict(values=[[100, 100, 100, 300], # 1st column
                       [90, 90, 90, 270]], # 2nd column
               line_color='darkslategray',
               fill_color='lightcyan',
               align='left'))
])

fig.update_layout(width=500, height=300)
fig.show()
```

i expect the values 300 and 270 in a different color. thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to change the color of a row / cell in plotly tables. You just have to mention which color to use for each cell/row.

See an example below to know how to color by row,

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd


data = {'A Scores' : [100, 100, 100, 300], 'B Scores' : [90, 90, 90, 270]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['color'] = ['rgb(189, 215, 231)', 'rgb(189, 215, 231)', 'rgb(189, 215, 231)', 'rgb(8, 81, 156)']

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
  header=dict(
    values=["A Scores", "B Scores"],
    line_color='white', fill_color='white',
    align='center', font=dict(color='black', size=12)
  ),
  cells=dict(
    values=[df["A Scores"], df["B Scores"]],
    line_color=df.color, fill_color=[df.color],
    align='center', font=dict(color='black', size=11)
  ))
])

fig.show()
```

[image: Table]

Plotly offers more customization options to tables. Read docs for more : [docs](https://plotly.com/python/table/)